# Node won't change to newest version (14.4.0)

Tags: node.js, homebrew, failed-installation, nvm

I am having troubles upgrading Node.js. I have tried multiple things such as

```
brew upgrade node
brew unlink node && brew link node
```

which gives

```
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/node/14.4.0... 0 symlinks removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/14.4.0... 33 symlinks created
```

but when I run `node -v` I get `v12.16.3`. I also tried with nvm instead, following tutos online and then running `n 14` outputs a large list of file location with "Permission denied" attached. And when I run `sudo n 14`, I get the following

```
installed : v14.4.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
  active : v12.16.3 at /Users/JoeDane/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/bin/node
```

I feel like there is a straightforward way to tell my terminal to use the /usr/local/bin/node but I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have both `nvm` and `node` installed, and the node version managed by `nvm` actually shadows the brew installed `node` version.

You can either uninstall `nvm` or prepend your `PATH` like `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`, I think it would work.

If you still run into the issue, please also attach `echo $PATH` for debugging.